# Sending http requests from Android to server for every view in recyclerviewholder

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-volley, retrofit2

I need help :)

So I need to send API call to server for every view of file when it's displayed on the screen in recyclerview, it will probably send 500-1000 requests per users session or even more so I don't want to basicly ddos server when 100.000 people start scrolling :)
example:  imagege_viewed for every Instagram photo you ever see when you scroll feed

I think that I know that Volley Retrofit  or Async could handle it but I need to figure out best way to do it so any help would mean a lot.

I need to call UpdateView(file_id); every time image is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider persisting your information in local storage before overcalling the api.

For example you can use [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/) (The one i'm using) or [Realm](https://realm.io/). After that you can batch every request you have and send it in one call instead of calling the api for each view visited.

You can even schedule the task to be run when the user is not using your application. You can see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ecz5WDZoJok) video for that.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for help.. will look in to it